# Why Use 'new' When Using AsyncTask

Tags: android

When using `AsyncTask` in android, I have to use like this,

```
new MyAsyncTask().execute()
```

I have to make new instance If I want to use AsyncTask.
But I wonder why I have to do.

I just want to use it like,

```
private MyAsyncTask task;
...
private void foo()
{
    ...
    task.excute();
}
```

BUT I can't.

And I want to know why it doesn't work.

If you give me answer, I'm very appreciated.

Comment: because you need to instantiate the class

Comment: because `execute` is not static method so you will need to use class object to call `execute`

Comment: You need to explicitly create the object (e.g. the constructor needs t to be called). As there are a lot of things going on in the constructor, you cannot call that one when declaring as in your second example, so you need to actually call that. It's how java works. But the bottomline is: you need to call the constructor, because that does some work

Answer (score 3):

`execute()` is a method of `AsyncTask`. If you want to invoke then you need to create an instance of `Asynctask`.

If you want to execute a method of a class you need to instantiate and then call the appropriate methods.

`task.excute();` will give you `NUllPointerException`.

```
task = new MyAsyncTask();
task.execute();
```

You may also want to check

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html

Look at the public methods as suggested by prosper k it is not a static method

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: @MrSnowflake he has not accpeted any of his other answers. may be providing a link to meta helps

Answer (score 3):

Java is not RAII. You always need to create an instance of a class, because you cannot execute methods on a class directly unless the method is static. But then still the syntax would be different.

What you can do is more like this:

```
private MyAsyncTask task;
…
private void foo() {
    task = new MyAsyncTask();
    …
    task.execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of Java not Android. In java, something like:

```
    MyAsynkTask task;
```

doesn't **create** an object. In this step you have only **declared** a variable. To use any method of your object (e.g. task.execute()) you have to **instantiate** an object (i.e. actually create one); like:

```
    task = new MyAsyncTask();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html) link for basics of "new" keyword. Basically it is use for **Instantiating a Class.The new operator instantiates a class by allocating memory for a new object and returning a reference to that memory. The new operator also invokes the object constructor.**
Hope this helps you.